# How to access the Camera from one device to another through wifi or Bluetooth

Tags: android-camera, android-bluetooth

Is it possible to access camera of an android device from another android device through, wifi or Bluetooth , Consider two devices a Samsung and moto g devices, is it possible to capture images in Samsung with moto g camera?

Answer (score 0):

There are many applications designed for this purpose. Ex: Camera Remote.